# Find a basis of set of polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I try to understand concept of basis in the book "Linear Algebra Done Right". I don't need any help in solving, but I have some questions to this topic and it would be great if somebody check whether I understand it right or not and explain me what I don't understand. I will provide some example to do everything easier.

1. Consider the $U:=\{p \in \mathbb P_4(\mathbb R): p(6)=0\}$ (Find the basis)

$\textbf{My solution:}$ Since $p \in \mathbb P_4(\mathbb R)$ the generic form of it $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2 x^2+a_3x^3+ a_4x^4$. For every $p \in \mathbb P_4(\mathbb R)$ we have $p(6)=0$ and therefore $0=a_0+6a_1+36a_2+216a_3+1296a_4$ hence $$a_0=-6a_1-36a_2-216a_3-1296a_4 \quad  (1)$$
and we have $$p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2 x^2+a_3x^3+ a_4x^4=-6a_1-36a_2-216a_3-1296a_4+a_1x+a_2 x^2+a_3x^3+ a_4x^4$$ so $$p(x)=a_1(x-6)+a_2(x^2-36)+a_3(x^3-216)+a_4(x^4-1296)$$
therefore $((x-6),(x^2-36),(x^3-216),(x^4-1296))$ is a basis.

$\textbf{The first question is:}$ Why did we put equation (1) in the generic form of polynomial?

$\textbf{My answer:}$ Because we made from the generic form of polynomial, the polynomial of form of $U$. Am I right?

$\textbf{Solution that I found:}$ Since we know that $p(6)=0$, we can write $$p(x)=(x-6)q(x)$$ where $q(x) \in \mathbb P_3(\mathbb R)$. So instead of to find the basis of $U$, we can find the basis of $W:=\{(x-6)q(x): q(x) \in \mathbb P_3(\mathbb R)\}$,which will ultimately give the basis of $U$.Naturally the basis of $$\mathbb P_3(\mathbb R)$$ is $1,x,x^2,x^3$

$\textbf{My second question is:}$ Why will the basis of $W$ give me the basis of $U$? I can check, that these vectors are linearly independent and span $U$. But before checking it, how can I understand, that this idea is right?

For the third question I have another example.

Consider $U:=\{p \in \mathbb P_4(\mathbb R): p'(6)=0\}$ (Find the basis).

$\textbf{My solution is similar to solution in problem 1}$. So I got the basis is $$(1,x,(x^3-18x^2),(x^4-216x^2))$$

$\textbf{Solution, that I found:}$ the vectors $(x-6)^k$ $\>(0\leq k\leq4)$ form a basis of $P_4$. Therefore the general element $p(x)$ of $P_4$ can be written as
$$p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^4 a_k(x-6)^k,\qquad a_k\in{\mathbb R}\quad (0\leq k\leq4)\ .$$
One computes
$$p''(6)=2a_2\ .$$
It follows that $p''(6)=0$ is equivalent with $a_2=0$. A basis of $U$ is therefore given by
$$\bigl(1, \ x-6, \ (x-6)^3, \ (x-6)^4\bigr)$$

$\textbf{The third question is}$ Is it necessary to take vectors of form $(x-6)$ in this sum? Or standard basis the form $1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4$ will also work? Needless to say, that we also use the fact, that $p''(6)=0$ at the end and we will also get $a_2=0$. I will get a little bit another basis, but it's not be uniquely. So is it possible to take $$p(x)= \sum_{k=0}^4 a_kx^k \quad \text{instead of} \ p(x)=\sum_{k=0}^4 a_k(x-6)^k$$?

Comment: The first thing is to confirm that you are dealing with finite dimensional linear spaces (you are). Then you can find the basis any way you want. Often answers are presented 'after the fact' in a nice way with all the dirty work removed, leaving the impression that somehow the answer just popped out that way.

Comment: For example, in the first case, you have a formula that gives $a_0$ if you know the other coefficients. You could use this to generate a basis. Set $a_1=1$ and all others (except $a_0$ of course) to zero. This will give a polynomial of the form $x+a_0 = x-6$. Repeat for $a_2,...$. (You would need to confirm that this is indeed a  basis for the space.)

Comment: @copper.hat the problem, that I don't understand, why do we have right to do this? Set $a_1=1$ and others to zero. Honestly, I don't see, how you got $x+a_0=x-6$. And why is $a_1=1$ and all others to zero and $\textbf{not}$ $a_1=2$ and all others to five. Or something else?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no single recipe. You do know that a polynomial is in $U$ **iff** its coefficients satisfy (1). The problem is to find a systematic way to generate a collection of polynomials that satify that equation **and** form a basis. It helps to know the dimension of $U$ first, note that if we define the linear functional $f(p) = p(6)$ then $U = \ker f$, and since $\dim {\cal R} f = 1$ we see that $\dim U = 4-1 = 3$, so we are looking for $3$ linearly independent polynomials.

Comment: @copper.hat ok, so far I understand, the first question I answered right. Can you help me please with another two?

Comment: When you substitute $a_0$ into the formula for the polynomial, you have the most general form of an element of $U$. So, one way to look at the problem it to select three groups of coefficients $(a_1,...,a_3)$ such that the resulting polynomials are linearly independent.

Comment: Hmm, no, note that $W=U$. You can use a basis of $P_3(\mathbb R)$ to generate a **spannning set** for $W$. Then check that these are linearly independent, in which case we know that it is a basis for $W$ (and hence $U$).

Comment: Note that the polynomial $p(x) = 1$ is not an element of $W=U$.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry, it was my mistake, I wanted to write $1,x,x^2,x^3$ is basis of $\mathbb P_3(\mathbb R)$ I edited it. Thank you

Comment: @copper.hat so I don't understand why $(x-6)$ multiply by basis of $\mathbb P_3(\mathbb R)$ will give us the basis of $U$. I hope, you will understand what I mean. I can prove that it works by showing that these vectors are linearly independent and span $U$. But before this checking, why must I understand, that it's right?

Comment: Since $W$ is made up of elements of the form $(x-6) u$, where $u \in U$, then any element of $W$ can be created from the elemens $(x-6)b_k$, where $b_k$ form a basis of $U$. (Any element of $U$ is of the form $\sum_k \alpha_k b_k$ so any element of $W$ can be written as $\sum_k (x-6) \alpha_k b_k$).

Comment: @copper.hat but @w@ is not made up this form. $W$ has form $(x-6)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ polynomial of degree 3, isn't?

Comment: Sorry, replace $U$ by $\mathbb{R}_3$ in my last comment. Are you asking why $U=W$?

Comment: @copper.hat no problem) yes, so we have three linearly independent vector $v_0,v_1,v_2,v_3$ because they are basis of $W$. If I multiply them by $(x-6)$, why will I get $U$?

Comment: I am not exactluy sure what you are asking. Every element $p \in W$ satisfies $p(6)=0$, so we must have $W \subset U$. If $p \in U$, we know that $p(6) = 0$ so $(x-6)$ is a factor, and we can write $p(x) = (x-6) q(x)$ where $q $ has $\max$ degree $3$, so $p\in W$.

Comment: @copper.hat my question was, why the basis of $W$ will automatically give me a basis for $U$. But I think I understood it. Thank you for your answer. Can I ask the last one? You said that we can put $a_1=1$ and all others except $a_1$ equal to zero. Can we put any numbers what I want? Your choice is 1 and 0, because its the simple way, isn't?

Comment: Still unsure what you are asking. In my previous comment I showed that $U=W$, so a basis of one must be a basis of the other.

Comment: All elements of $U$ have coefficients of the form $p$ above (with $a_0$ from (1)). You want a basis. If we pick coefficients of the form $(1,0,...), (0,1,..),...$ then the leading term will be $x^k$ for some $k$ so the resulting polynomials will be linearly independent. Since there are $4$ of them, they must then form a basis.

Comment: Note that $\dim U = 4$, I wrote something incorrect above.